# Bootstrap 2 columns with nested columns

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My content of a single website is represented by a `container`. A container contains a `row` and within a row one `box`.

Now I need the following layout in my box:

- Two columns, the first 1/3, the seconds 2/3 of the width.
- 2nd column: contains opening hours. I need also 2 columns with 1/3 and 2/3

**Example (aim):**

```
Columns 1 (1/3)                      | Columns 2 (2/3)
Column 1.1 (1/3) | Column 1.2 (2/3)  | 
Mo-Fr            | 8 am - 8 pm       |
Sa               | 10 am - 5 pm      |
```

**My Code:**

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
        <div class="box">

            <!-- Column 1 -->
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <hr>
                <h2 class="intro-text text-center">Opening Hours</h2>
                <hr>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        Mo-Fr:<br>
                        <br>
                        Sa:
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        8:00 - 12:30<br>
                        14:30 - 18:00<br>
                        07:30 - 13:00
                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                ...

            <!-- Column 2 -->
            <div class="col-lg-9">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

**My Problem:**

It works on full screen, but if I decrease my browser (to emulate a mobile device), the columns are among each other like:

```
Mo-Fr                 
Sa                
8 am - 8 pm  
10 am - 5 pm
```

Comment: You also need to specify the columns to be occupied for `smaller and mobile version by using col-xs-**` here you only used col-lg-** for more dynamic layout use multiple classes like `div class = "col-xs-3 col-lg-3"`

Comment: @Mahaveersharma thank you, its working

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="box">
<!-- Column 1 -->
    <div class="col-lg-3">
            <hr>
            <h2 class="intro-text text-center">Opening Hours</h2>
            <hr>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-3">
                    Mo-Fr:<br>
                    <br>
                    Sa:
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6">
                    8:00 - 12:30<br>
                    14:30 - 18:00<br>
                    07:30 - 13:00
                  </div>
              </div>
              <br>
              ...  
          <!-- Column 2 -->
           <div class="col-lg-9">
              ...
          </div>
      </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: try with the class `container-fluid`.

Comment: i dont think this will work because in Mobile views the divs will still take up 12 columns.